# How to make a svg-filled background go animating by pure CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Is there any pure CSS way to create some effect like this? to make it easier to understand, I have make a demo with JavaScript to implement this.

http://jsfiddle.net/78h823dd/3/

```
function renderHandler() {
  x+=offset;
  $("#debug").val(x);
  $('.test').css('background-position', x.toString() + 'px 0');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can animate it quite easily with CSS using the following:

```
@keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: 100% 50%; }
}
```

and by adding this to the css for the class:

```
.test {
  /* rest of code */
  animation: animatedBackground 5s linear infinite;
}
```

Changing the 5s to a lower time will speed it up and a higher time will slow it down. However I'm not aware of a way to dynamically change the speed of  it without JavaScript.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7f44hu11/3/)

Comment: when the speed is slow, the FPS seems to be not good. Looks like it's changing one by one pixel. If it can be more smooth, it'd be great.

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo It's a little bit more convoluted but CSS animations work better on transform properties than the background-image property, so by putting an absolute `<div>` as the background and animating that with transform you can get better performance. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7f44hu11/4/